# Regex for prohibiting surrogates in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a regex to match the following condition:

> shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0
>   other than 0024 ( $ ), 0040 ( @ ), or 0060 (‘), nor one in the range
>   D800 through DFFF inclusive.

I wrote the following regex:

```
PATTERN = ([\u0024\u0040\u0060]|(?![\u0000-\u00A0])|(?![\u8000-\udfff]))
```

and use it for search as follows

```
str = #some str
search = re.search(PATTERN, str, re.UNICODE)
```

The thing that I'm confused by is that `\u8000 - \udfff` are surrogate

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IkwqBf/1).

But running such regex in my script seems to work fine. Is it a correct way to use regex to filter out such characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging some, I have found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574077/12167858

In short: The characters in that range are simply **not a thing** in wide Unicode strings, at least in python 3. The execution of your regex works because no such characters are contained to begin with. Python seems to ignore the illogical command and move on. But because of this, `regex101` marks it as an error despite running fine.

To answer your question: Well yes, but no as well. It simply won't do a thing. I would suggest removing the `\u8000-\udfff` part.